# invoke telnet as a shell command from Groovy

Tags: linux, shell, groovy, io, telnet

How can I get groovy, in this case groovysh, to invoke the telnet client so that replies from the server are displayed?

```
thufir@mordor:~$ 
thufir@mordor:~$ groovysh
Groovy Shell (1.8.6, JVM: 1.8.0_72)
Type 'help' or '\h' for help.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
groovy:000> 'telnet rainmaker.wunderground.com 3000'.execute()
===> java.lang.UNIXProcess@8458f04
groovy:000> 
groovy:000> exit
thufir@mordor:~$
```

I'm aware of numerous telnet libraries for Java, but in this case, want to to execute telnet as a shell command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`execute()` gives you a Java `Process`. In your case a `UNIXProcess`. If telnet executes in a non-interactive fashion (ex. you can pipe it's output to a file), then you can read the `Process`'s `InputStream` to get it's output:

```
'telnet rainmaker.wunderground.com 3000'.execute().inputStream.eachLine { line ->
    println line
}
```

Comment: is there a way to get the last line?  "Press Return to continue:"